# Which approach to use for matching new students to a coach based on survey answers

Tags: machine-learning, classification, training-data

There are new students which should automatically be assigned to a coach (which than teaches the students).

The students fill out a survey with 30 multiple choice questions beforehand from which the answers should be used as our features.

My idea is to handle this as a multiclass classification problem where every coach is a class and we can match a student based on their survey answers.

One problem is, that the training data is very small with only a few hundred student-coach matches with survey answers made by hand which can be used as the training data.

Does this approach can yield good results for this problem or is there a better solution/approach for it?

Comment: It's impossible to know what approach is the best. You should try multiple approaches and compare them with a held-out validation set or k-fold cross validation. If you don't have much data, perhaps use a relatively small validation set (e.g. hold out 10% of the training data). You should probably focus on simple methods like logistic regression if you have little training data.

Comment: Thanks for your input. My question was more in the direction if regarding this as a multiclass-classification problem is the correct approach. E.g. if I had students which get re-assigned to another coach in the next year and have visited several classes (coaches) before I could handle it as a recommendation problem.

Comment: I see. That depends on a lot of details about the problem setting, and only you can decide whether or not this approach is reasonable. For instance, if coaches can come and go (e.g. label shift), then you may have to do something tricky to account for this. Otherwise, I don't see anything wrong with formulating the problem as multiclass classification. After all, you're trying to map a feature space to exactly one of many discrete labels; I'm pretty sure that's the definition of multiclass classification. But again, if you have other ideas, you should try them all and compare.

Comment: Can you elaborate shortly on some ways to account for new coaches? I assumed if a new coach (label) comes in, we have to create a new training set for this label and retrain the model.

Comment: The solution you mentioned is valid. If you collect data on the coaches, you may be able to cluster students and assign each coach to a cluster based on their own features. When a new coach is introduced, you only have to remap coaches to clusters which likely requires less new data than remapping students to coaches. One-shot and few-shot learning methods might also allow you to remap students to new coaches without much new data. The point is, there are many solutions; you should read a few articles and papers on these topics and make an informed decision based on your exact problem.